# Ionic 4 alpha, How to build apk and how to run in emulator?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

How do I build ionic 4(alpha) apk and also how to run project in emulator.
I used command

```
ionic cordova build android 
ionic cordova run android
```

for building apk and for run in emulator, it can be work to build apk but apk can not giving any response in mobile device(android) and also not giving any response in my emulator. so what is solution for it?

we are using

```
cordova version 8.0.0, 
angular version 6.0.9,  
emulator type and version Android 7.0.0 –
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please make sure to include enough information about your configuration to get relevant help. In your case, you should probably mention your Ionic info (exact version of lib, cli, whether you use angular, its version, cordova version, OS and version, emulator type and version, etc.)

Comment: Have you updated your [Android SDK tools to version 27](https://www.andreszsogon.com/using-android-8-and-9-emulators-without-android-studio/) already? Android 8 emulator won't work with anything older.